# Construct a DFA based on this language

Tags: computer-science, automata

Let $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ be a language of any alphabet $\Sigma$. Let $move(L)$ describe the language which contains every string such that it takes the last letter in $x \in L$ and puts it to the front.

How can we construct a DFA $A$ for $move(L)$?

I started off by looking at what the DFA for L would be like:

- Say $s = s_0 s_1 s_2 ... s_n$ where $s_i \in \Sigma$ is a string this DFA accepts
- it will go by some path of states $q_0q_1...q_n$. I made the last state transition to the first in $A$ but something tells me this isn't right so I'm not sure how to move on.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Is $L$ a regular language? Because if its not, no DFA can accept it...

Comment: Yes, It is regular.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, I added my thought process to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\ A=\big(Q,\Sigma, \delta, q_0, F\big)\ $ be a DFA which accepts $\ L\ $. Let
\begin{align}
Q'&=\big(\Sigma\times Q\big)\,\cup \big\{q_0'\big\}\\
F'&=\big\{(s,q)\in \Sigma\times Q\,\big|\,\delta(q,s)\in F\big\}\\
\delta'(q',s)&=\cases{(s,q_0)&if $\ q'=q_0'$\\
\big(\sigma,\delta(q,s)\big)&if $\ q'=(\sigma,q)\in\Sigma\times Q\ $.}
\end{align}
Then $\ S'=\big(Q',\Sigma, \delta', q_0', F'\big)\ $ is a DFA which accepts $\ move(L)\ $.

If $\ \xi\in\Sigma^*\ $, and $\ q_n\ $ is the state of $ A\ $ after it has processed the string $\ \xi\ $, then $\ \big(s_0,q_n\big)\ $ will be the state of $\ A' $ after it has processed the string $\ s_0\xi\ $, and $\ \big(s_0,q_n\big)\in F'\ $ if and only if $\ \delta(q_n,s_0)\in F\ $—that is, $\ A'\ $ accepts the string $\  s_0\xi\ $ if and only if $\ A\ $ accepts the string $\ \xi s_0\ $.

**Reply to query from OP in comments**

In general, the minimal-state DFA for the language $\ L\ $ will have strictly fewer states than the minimal-state DFA for $\ move(L)\ $, so if you're given a DFA for $\ L\ $ it will not always possible to construct a DFA for $\ move(L)\ $ which has the same set of states.  If
\begin{align}
L=\ &\big\{a^{n_1}b^{n_2}c^{n_3}\,\big|\,n_1\ge0, n_2\ge0, n_3\ge1\,\big\}\\
\cup &\big\{a^{n_1}b^{n_2}d^{n_3}\,\big|\,n_1\ge0, n_2\ge0, n_3\ge1\,\big\}\\
\cup &\big\{a^{n_1}b^{n_2}e^{n_3}\,\big|\,n_1\ge0, n_2\ge0, n_3\ge1\,\big\}\ ,
\end{align}
for instance, it is easy to construct a $5$-state DFA which accepts $\ L\ $. However,
\begin{align}
move(L)=\ &\big\{ca^{n_1}b^{n_2}c^{n_3}\,\big|\,n_1\ge0, n_2\ge0, n_3\ge0\,\big\}\\
\cup &\big\{da^{n_1}b^{n_2}d^{n_3}\,\big|\,n_1\ge0, n_2\ge0, n_3\ge0\,\big\}\\
\cup &\big\{ea^{n_1}b^{n_2}e^{n_3}\,\big|\,n_1\ge0, n_2\ge0, n_3\ge0\,\big\}\ ,
\end{align}
and it is not difficult to show that any DFA which accepts $\ move(L)\ $ must have at least $7$ states (by using the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem), for instance).

**What if $\ \epsilon\in L\ $?**

[Dromniscience's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3888628/construct-a-dfa-based-on-this-language/3888853#3888853) and [LetmeKnow](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/716983/letmeknow)'s comment below have alerted me to the fact that the above answer implicitly (and inadvertently on my part) makes an assumption which is not necessarily justified—namely that the *move* operation will eliminate the empty string $\ \epsilon\ $ if it happens to be in $\ L\ $.  Because $\ q_0'\not\in F'\ $ in the above definition of $\ A'\ $ the empty string $\ \epsilon\ $  can't be in the language accepted by $\ A'\ $.

However, since the OP doesn't specify how the *move* operation will deal with the empty string, it doesn't seem justified to me to assume that $\ \epsilon\not\in move(L)\ $ whenever $\ \epsilon\in L\ $. If, instead, $\ \epsilon\in L\ \implies\epsilon\in move(L)\ $ then the definition of $\ A'\ $ would have to be modified as follows:
\begin{align}
Q'&=\big(\Sigma\times Q\big)\,\cup \big\{q_0'\big\}\\
F'&=\cases{\big\{(s,q)\in \Sigma\times Q\,\big|\,\delta(q,s)\in F\big\}&if $\ q_0\not\in F$\\
\big\{(s,q)\in \Sigma\times Q\,\big|\,\delta(q,s)\in F\big\}\cup\big\{q_0'\big\}&if $\ q_0\in F$}\\
\delta'(q',s)&=\cases{(s,q_0)&if $\ q'=q_0'$\\
\big(\sigma,\delta(q,s)\big)&if $\ q'=(\sigma,q)\in\Sigma\times Q\ $.}
\end{align}

Comment: what does it mean for the transition function to map to a pair?

Comment: The states of a DFA can be *any* finite set.  In this case, all the states of $\ S'\ $ except the starting state are members of $\ \Sigma\times Q\ $—i.e. pairs comprising one member of $\ \Sigma\ $ and one member of $\ Q\ $. The only pairs which the transition function $\ \delta'\ $ maps to are all of this form—i.e. they are *states* of the DFA $\ S'\ $.

Comment: I've spent a while trying to translate this DFA into a DFA where the states are only members of $Q$, but I'm not getting anywhere with it. Could you help me out?

Comment: Hey, I have a question, is $s \in \Sigma$ or in $\Sigma^*$ and would this handle the empty string $\epsilon$ if $L$ accepted it?

Comment: @LetmeKnow I have now modified my answer in response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to actually move the last transition to the front. Instead, why don't you simply remember the first letter and check whether it will lead to a final state in the original DFA?

Please think it over before you continue reading.
If we denote the original DFA as $L = \langle Q, \Sigma, \delta, q_0, F\rangle$, we can construct a new DFA for $move(L) = \langle Q', \Sigma, \delta', q_{init}, F'\rangle$, where
\begin{align}
Q' &= \{q_{init}\} \cup \Sigma \times Q \\
F' &= \{(a, q)\mid \delta(a, q)\in F\} \\
\delta'((a, q), b) &= (a, \delta(q,b)) \\
\delta'(q_{init}, b) &= (b, q_0) \\
\end{align}
Since $\epsilon$ is never in $move(L)$, $F'$ suffices.

Comment: what does it mean for the transition function to map to a pair?

Comment: This pair is a component of $Q'$. Recall that $\delta$ is always a mapping from $Q\times \Sigma$ to $Q$.

Comment: is b a member of $\Sigma^*$? or of $\Sigma$?